# Confusion regarding eigenfunction expansions and Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series, boundary-value-problem

I am aware of the fact that a Fourier series is an example of an expansion of orthogonal functions. In particular, it can be shown that the sequence of eigenfunctions for the periodic Sturm-Liouville boundary value problem
$y'' + y*\lambda = 0$; $y(0) = y(2\pi)$, $y'(0) = y'(2\pi)$
forms the orthogonal basis for the Fourier series:
${\frac{1}{2}, \cos(x), \sin(x), \cos(2x), \sin(2x)...}$. However, this is not an *orthonormal* basis. Thus when we are finding the coefficients for the Fourier expansion, we must divide by a scaling constant to account for this. Do the formulas for the Fourier coefficients account for this in some way?

Comment: Check the orthogonality condition and you will see whether a prefactor is present or not. Anyway, vectors (or even the considered inner product) can always be normalized afterwards.